# Post array to web api using IHttpActionResult not working in VB

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net, post, asp.net-web-api

I can use ajax and IHttpActionResult to post array to web api in C#.net (VS2017). However, it does not work after I convert the code to vb.net (VC2017). I only get 0 values for the variables. Here is my code:

Class:

```
Public Class Latlon
   Public Property latIn As Decimal
   Public Property lonIn As Decimal
End Class
```

API controller

```
<HttpPost>
Public Function Post(ByVal latlons As List(Of Latlon)) As IHttpActionResult
    Dim lat1 = latlons(0).latIn
    Return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, lat1)
End Function
```

ajax:

```
        var latlon = [
            { lat: 45, lon: -120 },
            { lat: 55, lon: -112 }
        ];
        alert(latlon)
        $.ajax({
            url: uri,
            method: "POST",
            data: { '': latlon } 
        }).done(function (result) {
            alert(result)
        }).fail(function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        });
```

Chrome F12
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your property names do not match

```
    var latlon = [
        { lat: 45, lon: -120 },
        { lat: 55, lon: -112 }
    ];
```

is not the same as in the VB class

```
Public Class Latlon
    Public Property latIn As Decimal
    Public Property lonIn As Decimal
End Class
```

try renaming the properties in the vb class

```
Public Class Latlon
    Public Property lat As Decimal
    Public Property lon As Decimal
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Ken! You saved me many hours. After the conversion, I changed variables names, which caused the problem. I did not realized it. Happy New Year!